# Converting string to html

Tags: html, coffeescript, meteor, handlebars.js

Currently I have a system in place where I have users that fill out a textarea with markdown text and store it in the server. Than when a client loads a page I want that markdown text converted to readable HTML. As it stands I have the markdown converting to a long HTML string, but have no way of injecting the html into my page as it is just a string right now.

This is what I have tried so far...

**Coffeescript File**

```
Template.messages.convertMsg = (message) ->
    doc = document.createElement('div')
    doc.innerHTML = marked(message)
    doc.getElementsByTagName( 'a' )
```

**HTML File**

```
<div class="chat-message-contents">{{convertMsg message}}</div>
```

An example html string might be...

`'<li><a href="#adding-two">Adding Two</a>'`

Comment: Have you had a look at the [showdown package](http://docs.meteor.com/#showdown)?

Comment: if the mark down has been converted to html/string would it work to just pass this to handlebars ie. template = Handlebars.compile(convertedMarkDown) now you can place it on the page. My first thought would be jQuery $("#target-element").html(this.tempalte()); no idea what the syntax would in be coffescript

Comment: @Quince: Don't use jQuery in Meteor when a standard approach is sufficient.

Comment: ah ok never used Meteor, I was just providing an example of how I add my handlebar templates as I use backbone in my day to day, of course use what makes most sense.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe I'm missing something, but can't you just place the html string in a triple-bracket?

```
<div class="chat-message-contents">{{{convertMsg message}}}</div>
```

This would make sure that the html is not escaped, i.e., it is rendered.

Comment: I was just unaware about this. Still fairly new to all of this. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

The easiest way is to add a standard `showdown` package:

```
mrt add showdown
```

Then simply write:

```
<template name="...">
  {{#markdown}}{{message}}{{/markdown}}
</template>
```

Note that white spaces matter in markdown, so if you did

```
{{#markdown}}
  {{message}}
{{/markdown}}
```

The first line of message would be indented, which would cause a bad formatting.

---

Alternatively, if you're confident that you prefer your own Markdown parser, use triple brace or `Handlebars.SafeString`. Also a good idea would be to create your helper globally, so that other templates can display markdown as well.

```
UI.registerHelper('convertMsg', function(options) {
  var html = marked(options.fn(this));
  return new Handlebars.SafeString(html);
});
```